# button within movieclip in actionscript 3.0

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, navigation

I have a button inside a movieclip that I want to navigate to another movieclip in the main timeline

i used this code, but the button doesnt do anything:

```
btnHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_3);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("Menu");
}
```

how do you navigate to the main timeline within a movieclip?

Comment: 1. Make sure you actually have a frame labeled "Menu" in your main timeline.   2.   Are you sure the parent of this code block is the main timeline?   You could go right to root:   `MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop("Menu");`

Comment: tried that already it didn't work either

Comment: what error's do you get?

Comment: no errors, it just does not go to the frame

Answer (score 0):

The code is fine. If you are using that code as it is, make sure it's inside the `btnHome` parent movieclip. That code Will not work if it's on the main timeline or elsewhere.

```
btnHome.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_3);    
function fl_MouseClickHandler_3(event:MouseEvent):void{
    MovieClip(this.parent).gotoAndStop("Menu");
};
```